# Question about Heisenberg's uncertainty.

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Heisenberg said that we can't tell precisely both the location of an electron and the momentum of it in the same instant. If we observe one thing, the other is changed. How he concluded this principle?

I want to say if we want to locate an electron we'll send photons to it, but after hitting the electrons, will the photons ever come back? It'll lose its energy and transfer it to electron changing its momentum right? How he concluded this principle?

Also what will happen if by some means we're able to observe both things accurately? What will be the benefit?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) on this describes it very well.  The uncertainty principle is fundamental to waves.  Do you have a more specific question?  Yours is highly broad.

Comment: This and related questions have been asked and answered on this site several times before. One of those can be found as one of my most recent posts through my user page; it addresses how wave-particle duality leads straight to the uncertainty principle.

Comment: I was just curious to find how had Heisenberg concluded his principle? And if we somehow we are able to make a Heisenberg compensator type thing which can actually tell us about both the uncertain things (momentum and position) with certainty. What'll be it's benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also what will happen if by some means we're able to observe both
>   things accurately?

You're assuming that both 'things' (position and momentum) have definite values simultaneously.

But, according to quantum mechanics, *they don't*.

Whatever a quantum mechanical particle *is*, it is *not* an entity that can exist in a state of definite position *and* definite momentum simultaneously.

So, you need to do some more reading and thinking about the uncertainly principle.

From the Wikipedia article "[Uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)":

> **Historically, the uncertainty principle has been confused with a
>   somewhat similar effect in physics, called the observer effect**, which
>   notes that measurements of certain systems cannot be made without
>   affecting the systems.
>
> Heisenberg offered such an observer effect at the quantum level as a physical "explanation" of quantum uncertainty. It has since become clear,
>   however, that the uncertainty principle is inherent in the properties of all
>   wave-like systems, and that it arises in quantum mechanics simply due to
>   the matter wave nature of all quantum objects.
>
> **Thus, the uncertainty principle actually states a fundamental property of
>   quantum systems, and is not a statement about the observational success of
>   current technology.**

Comment: Okay, so basically it's a principle about the wave nature and not the particle. But then it speaks about the uncertainty in momentum. Do the waves have momentum?

Comment: @Adarsh, a *classical* particle is vastly different from a *quantum* particle.  The first step towards understanding quantum 'weirdness' is to understand that "particle", in QM, does not mean "point like entity".  A quantum particle is an entity that can exhibit wave-like *or* point-like properties, depending on the context.  See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality